# Django URLField with custom scheme

Tags: django

Django's [`django.db.models.URLField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#urlfield) uses a [`django.core.validators.URLValidator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/validators/#urlvalidator):

```
class URLField(CharField):
    default_validators = [validators.URLValidator()]
```

Since it does not specify the schemes to accept, URLValidator defaults to this set:

```
schemes = ['http', 'https', 'ftp', 'ftps']
```

I want my URLField to accept `ssh://` URLs, so I tried this:

```
class SSHURLField(models.URLField):
  '''URL field that accepts URLs that start with ssh:// only.'''
  default_validators = [URLValidator(schemes=['ssh'])]
```

However when I try to save a new object with a valid `ssh://` URL, I get rejected.

This also happens if I skip inheriting from URLField and inherit from CharField directly: (**Edit**: Actually this does work after I recreated my database. I'm not sure why the former doesn't work.)

```
class SSHURLField(models.CharField):
  '''URL field that accepts URLs that start with ssh:// only.'''
  default_validators = [URLValidator(schemes=['ssh'])]

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['max_length'] = 64
    super(SSHURLField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

When I use the URLValidator directly in a test, it works:

```
def test_url(url):
  try:
    URLValidator(schemes=['ssh'])(url)
    return True
  except:
    return False

>>> test_url('ssh://example.com/')
True

>>> test_url('http://example.com/')
False
```

Comment: can you post the traceback?

Comment: @OregonTrail I'm not hitting an exception, but rather in the admin interface when I enter a `ssh://` URL, I get an "Enter a valid URL" error.

Comment: can you give an example of an `ssh://` uri that you are entering? change any sensitive info of course

Comment: I have a feeling it's failing to produce all of the return values here https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/validators.py#L123

Comment: Sure, as above (last code block), `ssh://example.com/` seems to pass the URLValidator's checks when I use it directly.

Comment: so you're sure that your model is using `SSHURLField`, and you've run migrations?

Comment: Yes. To completely make sure I just blew away my database, deleted all the migrations, created them anew from scratch, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Here's what I would usually do at this point. Open a python repl and run `import django.core.validators as v; print v.__file__`. Then edit that file and put a breakpoint at the top of the function `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`. Then run the django dev server and hit the breakpoint. You will have an interactive debugger to `s` step through and `n` next through the code.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm actually quite curious as I work with Django often.

Comment: This is a known issue with Django. See https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25594. I'd try overriding forms.URLField as well as fields.URLField.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As @IainDillingham mentioned in the comments, this is a bug in Django: overriding the default_validator of a subclassed ModelField does not necessarily override the default_validator of the FormField to which that base class is associated.

For your example, django.db.models.URLField, we can see its associated form field<sup>[0]</sup> is  django.forms.fields.URLField<sup>[1]</sup>. So the workaround here is to also override `def formfield(...)` for your customized `SSHURLField`, to reference a custom django.forms.fields.URLField subclass with the same validator, like so:

```
from django.core import validators
from django.db import models
from django.forms.fields import URLField as FormURLField

class SSHURLFormField(FormURLField):
    default_validators = [validators.URLValidator(schemes=['ssh'])]

class SSHURLField(models.URLField):  
    '''URL field that accepts URLs that start with ssh:// only.'''  
    default_validators = [validators.URLValidator(schemes=['ssh'])]  

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        return super(SSHURLField, self).formfield(**{
            'form_class': SSHURLFormField,
        })
```

[0] [https://github.com/django/django/blob/e17088a108e604cad23b000a83189fdd02a8a2f9/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py#L2275,L2293](https://github.com/django/django/blob/e17088a108e604cad23b000a83189fdd02a8a2f9/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L2275,L2293)
[1] https://github.com/django/django/blob/e17088a108e604cad23b000a83189fdd02a8a2f9/django/forms/fields.py#L650